# SmtpException: Cannot get IIS pickup directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7.5

I am trying to send email from my mvc application. Following is a part of the code I am using:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

The above code is giving the error:

> Cannot get IIS pickup directory SmtpException.

But if I run my Visual Studio as an Administrator, emails are sent successfully.

If I understand correctly, the issue is regarding access permissions, but I just can't figure out what.
If Relevant, the application is an intranet application with windows authentication.

Comment: The further you go, the more reasons you will find to always run Visual Studio as Admin. Debugging ASP.NET websites and using IIS are among those reasons. It has become one of the first things I make sure of on a new Development machine.
For a list of features/actions that require admin rights, see this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj662724.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the pickup directory manually:

// C#

```
client.PickupDirectoryLocation = ...;
```

Or set this in ASP.NET's Web.config instead:

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
                <specifiedPickupDirectory
                    pickupDirectoryLocation="..." />
                <network defaultCredentials="false" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't I have to set the pickup directory manually for admin. I mean why can't iis get the pickup directory for users who are not admin.

Comment: Sorry if that's lame. First application, new to all this.